# Phoenix: How to load a static tsv file for d3 graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js, elixir, phoenix-framework

I am working on a web app powered by Phoenix framework. I am trying to get a simple d3 line graph working, but somehow d3 cannot find the static `data.tsv` file I am trying to load into the JS file to draw the graph. Is there a specific way this is supposed to be done using Phoenix Elixir?

```
(function LineGraph() {

    var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%d-%b-%y");

    var x = d3.scaleTime()
        .rangeRound([0, width]);

    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .rangeRound([height, 0]);

    var line = d3.line()
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
        .y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });

    d3.tsv("../data/data.tsv", function(d) {
      d.date = parseTime(d.date);
      d.close = +d.close;
      return d;
    }, function(error, data) {
      if (error) throw error;

      x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
      y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.close; }));

      g.append("g")
          .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
          .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

      g.append("g")
          .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
          .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
        .append("text")
          .attr("fill", "#000")
          .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
          .attr("y", 6)
          .attr("dy", "0.71em")
          .style("text-anchor", "end")
          .text("Price ($)");

      g.append("path")
          .datum(data)
          .attr("class", "line")
          .attr("d", line);
    }); 
})();
```

I have tried creating the `data.tsv` file within the js directory, the data directory and also outside the web directory of the app.

Everytime I load the app, it tries to make an XHR request to the `data.tsv` and returns a 404.

How can I load the static file to draw the graph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such static files are usually stored in `priv/static`. One way to do this would be to put `data.tsv` in `priv/static/data/data.tsv`, and then adding `data` to the list of directories that `Plug.Static` should serve, by changing `lib/my_app/endpoint.txt` like this:

```
   plug Plug.Static,
     at: "/", from: :my_app, gzip: false,
-    only: ~w(css fonts images js favicon.ico robots.txt)
+    only: ~w(css fonts images js favicon.ico robots.txt data)
```

Comment: Yeah, that was the missing part. I think I read somewhere that if you add assets under `web/static/*` it gets copied under `priv/static/*`.